# Printing text from a control using the Print Dialog

Tags: .net, winforms, printing

I have a .NET 4.0 application and I need to take the text from a richtextbox control and print it using the print dialog control so the user can pick the printer to use. I know I could generate a file containing the text and print that, but I don't want to go this route if possible.

Is there a way to do what I'm wanting?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans' link was exactly what I needed. I decided to enhance it by offering another link.

C# version http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425

VB.NET version
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811401/en-us

I would have accepted his answer, but it was a comment and I didn't see how to accept that; I up-voted instead.

Comment: Hahaha.. Bounty removed, as it can't be awarded to a comment. Thank you for turning Hans' comment into a useful answer.